# How can I cange the marshal file thats opening with my project

Tags: c#, marshalling, desktop

Im trying to make a program wich opens a program (catia) and right now I get an error with "GetActiveObject".
I found out that my marshal file that opens with the program is diffrent from the one that has to open. Is it possible to change the marshal file that opens when i start the program?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOnVb.png)

Comment: There is only one `Marshal` class in .NET, so it's unclear what you mean.

Comment: Oh okay, I just dont know how to explain my problem tbh. I just need to get the method "GetActiveObject" to work.